# How to terminate a loop when the length of a list reaches a certain length?

Tags: list-manipulation, procedural-programming

If I start out with a list `A` with $n$ elements in it, how do I append elements to it until it has a length $N$?

For example if `A={1,2,3,4}`, and suppose I want to append the element `3.14` to `A` until the length of `A` is 10. I tried doing this with a While loop as follows:

```
While[Length[A]<10,Append[A,3.14]]
```

However Mathematica gets stuck computing it. How can one do this?

Answer (score 9):

If you introduce a length bound already, there is absolutely no reason for `Append`/`AppendTo`. Such a loop with `Append`/`AppendTo` has runtime complexity $O(n^2)$ because `Append`/`AppendTo` has to perform a copy of the whole list (which grows longer and longer). So a better practice is to initialize `A` as a list with the maximal length, to introduce an iteration counter `i` that actually stores the current length of the list, and just to *write* into `A[[i]]`. This way, only one entry of `A` is updated and the loop has complexity $O(n)$.

```
n = 10;
A = ConstantArray[0., n];
A[[1;;4]] = Range[1.,4.];
i = 4;
While[i < n,
 ++i;
 A[[i]] = 3.14
 ]
```

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
A={1,2,3,4};    
While[Length[A] < 10,
A = Append[A, 3.14]]
```

Which gives

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 3.14, 3.14, 3.14, 3.14, 3.14, 3.14}
```

When you call `Length[A]` inside the loop using `Append[]` it only remembers the A that you originally defined, so you need to explicitly 'update' its value. As mentioned in the comment below, `AppendTo[A, 3.14]` should do the trick:

```
While[Length[A] < 10,
AppendTo[A, 3.14]]
```

Worth reading the documentation of [AppendTo[]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AppendTo.html).

Comment: it might be worth mentioning that `AppendTo[A, 3.14]` also works since `AppendTo` automatically updates `A` while `Append` does not.

Answer (score 7):

[`PadRight`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PadRight.html) can be used.

In a general setting you will need to do `PadRight[A, N, element]`.

As in this case, you can use `PadRight[A, 10, 3.14]` and assign that list to `A` itself for appending. This is much faster than `While` loop approach for larger sets.

```
A = PadRight[A,10,3.14]
(*{1, 2, 3, 4, 3.14, 3.14, 3.14, 3.14, 3.14, 3.14}*)
```

**Another approach:**

```
A = Join[A, ConstantArray[elem, N-n]]
```

Here, we can use

```
A = Join[A, ConstantArray[3.14, 6]]
```

**Performance:** (as on Intel i5, 8 GB RAM)

```
A = {1,2,3,4}
(A = PadRight[A, 3.14, 10^6])//RepeatedTiming

B = {1,2,3,4}
(B = Join[B, ConstantArray[3.14, 10^6-4]])//RepeatedTiming

A == B
```

> {0.014, (a big list)}
>
> {0.072, (a big list)}
>
> True